# How to set Tool tip on a Button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to set tool tip on a button means when you place finger  on any button it shows some text on button , i know method in java awt but that not for java 
in java we can use

uiObj.setToolTiptext("text");

but in  android i am not getting any code  please s any help for setting tool tip on a button 
[image: Tool tip]

Comment: FYI majority of andrroid devices dont have joystick so you cant hover in them

Comment: how you can place cursor on device?

Answer (score 3):

Android doesn't have tool tips.  It is a touch-based UI.  Current touch sensors can't generally detect hovering in a way that tool tips would be useful.

Comment: tnx for ur hint , but in some cases when i place hover i want to diplay some text for info

Comment: Android doesn't even *have* a concept of hovering until 3.1.  Again this kind of interaction is not the primary way users interact with their devices, so if your UI is relying on it for user to understand your UI then it is *broken* because 99.9% of your users won't be able to hover.  If you still insist on doing this, you will need to write it yourself, using the APIs in 3.1 to monitor hovering and display the tool tip UI through a custom pop-up window or other mechanism: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onGenericMotionEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: Oh and it is worth noting that even the API in 3.1 is not really sufficient for doing tool tips, because it lacks information for when hovers enter and leave the UI.

Comment: suppose i have a Chart , in that when i place my hand i want to show points of (x,y) so that case tool tip is useful so any one have idea about to set tool tip

Comment: When you put your finger on it, you will receive onTouchEvent().  Watch for touch events and show your label as desired.  Again Android doesn't have a tool tip like thing as part of the platform; you will need to write that yourself.

Comment: LongPress on Action Bar icon item popup the item Text. Is this can be called a tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can give you an idea you can handle the first click on the item by showing your tooltip then in the second time you dismiss the tooltip and perform what your button does for real.

In Android you can show something like the tooltip using some quick action dialog. You can see this example:
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library, which I have created for myself for similar purposes. As usual, we want to show some descriptions for UI elements only after the first app opening.

**P.S.:** For future users: feel free to create feature requests, issues and any other feedback - I will enjoy it and try to help you!

https://github.com/mpetlyuk/initial_tips